# Assigning number to variable based on value of string in list in python

Tags: python, odoo-8

I am new to python.  I have a list which has strings, which in turn is used in a selection field in Odoo and based on the what the string is, a number is assigned to another variable.  I want to loop through the list and if the value of string matches what I am looking for, then an integer is then assigned to the number_value variable.  I have tried several different ways to accomplish this, but was not successful.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
  stringlist = [('a','abc'), ('b','def'), ('c','ghi')]
  number_value = 0 #Initialize variable to 0.

  for x in stringlist:
    if x in stringlist == 'abc':
      number_value = 1

    elif x in stringlist == 'def':
      number_value = 2

    else:
      number_value = 3
```

I have tried enumerate and also used both a for loop and a while loop, but I cannot get it to work.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is not formed correctly. You are checking to see if the tuple (immutable list) is in `stringlist` equaling to `abc` or `def`. You want to extract the 2nd element in the tuple and check to see if that equals `abc` or `def`. `x` in the context of the for loop is each tuple.

```
stringlist = [('a', 'abc'), ('b', 'def'), ('c', 'ghi')]
number_value = 0  # Initialize variable to 0.

for x in stringlist:
    if x[1] == 'abc':
        number_value = 1

    elif x[1] == 'def':
        number_value = 2

    else:
        number_value = 3
    print number_value
```

Comment: So, how would I be able for example to do a comparison based on the key? For example, if I say `if x[1] == 'a'`, then assign `number_value = 1`.  Or even doing a comparison based on the value itself as I had posted in the original code.  How would I go about doing either? Some code examples would help.  Thanks.

Comment: @OdooProgrammer `if x[0] == 'a'` This is a tuple. It is the same idea as a list except you cannot change a tuple. You are talking about it like it is a dictionary. Two different data structures. You could turn `stringlist` into a list of dicts like: `[{'a': 'abc'}, {'b': 'def'}, {'c': 'ghi'}]`

Comment: I don't think I can do that as it seems that Odoo requires it to be a list and not a dictionary, according to what I understand.  As such, I am stuck with using a list.  Is there anyway to loop through a tuple and look for a either the key or variable? I am not trying to modify the list in anyway.  All I want is to loop through the tuple and find either the key or value (whichever is possible), and then assign the number_value a number.